# Parent object only picks up first of child objects in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following set up:

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bill_items
  has_many :items, through :bill_items

  def add(item)
    BillItem.create(bill: self, item: item)
    update_total
  end

  def update_total
    total = 0
    bill_items.each do |item|
      total += item.price
    end
    self.update(total: total)
  end
end

class BillItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bill
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bill_items
end
```

When I run the following code it's fine:

```
Bill.first.add(Item.first)
Bill.first.add(Item.first)
Bill.first.total
>> 100
```

When I run the following code it bugs out:

```
c = Bill.first
c.add(Item.first)
c.add(Item.first)
c.total
>> 50
```

It only registers the first billitem for some reason. Some follow up code:

```
c.bill_items.count
>> 2

c.bill_items
>> [#<BillItem id: 1, price: 50, item_id: 1, bill_id: 1, created_at: "2019-10-11 11:08:58", updated_at: "2019-10-11 11:08:58">]
```

So it's only picking up the first BillItem.

Running `BillItem.all` picks up both billitems

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add records to an association just [use the methods generated by ActiveRecord](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
item = bill.items.new(name: 'Foo')
item = bill.items.create(name: 'Foo')
item = bill.items.create!(name: 'Foo')
bill.items << item
bill.items.push(item)
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly create the join record. Rails will do it for you.

If you want to update the total when an item is added use an [association callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks):

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bill_items
  has_many :items, through :bill_items, after_add: :update_total
end
```

As to the the `update_total` method - well its creative but there are much better ways to do it such as [Enumerable#sum](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/02/ruby-2-4-introduces-enumerable-sum.html) or using [ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) to let the database do it for you.

```
def update_total
  self.update(total: items.sum(:price))
end
```

Comment: Thanks max! I was being a dummy, as I suspected.

Comment: a followup question for you. I'm trying to update bill_items if they match conditions laid out by a `discount` model. I have the following call:
`bill_items.where(item_id: discount.item_id, price: old_price).update_all(price: new_price)`

It updates the actual bill_items but not in the association. By this I mean if afterwards I call `BillItem.pluck(:price)` I'll get the new price but if I call `bill.bill_items.pluck(:price)` I'll get the old price

Comment: Can you please ask this as a separate question? Follow up questions via comments are hell.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're adding the same item to the parent. Try making two items, each with a price of 50, and you should be able to get what you want.

If you insist on having one `item` with a price of 50 that you want to reference, you'll need to create a third class, and each new item there can reference the same price.

But the easiest solution from where you are is just to create a second `Item` and add that.

If you've already established a relationship between a Bill and an Item, you can't establish a second duplicate one as they're already associated. A Bill can't have the same Item added to it twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark. I'm adding a `BillItem` which references the same `Item`. That should be fine though right?

Comment: "If you've already established a relationship between a Bill and an Item, you can't establish a second duplicate one as they're already associated. A Bill can't have the same Item added to it twice." - this is not true at all. As long as you don't have a compound unique index and/or a validation you can create any number of duplicates in the join table.

Comment: There are actually two ways you can handle the quantity of items - either by making the combination of the foreign keys unique and adding a quantity column to the join table or by counting the number of rows in the join table. Both have pros and cons.

Comment: @max Sure you can create duplicate `BillItems`, but you're still not associating the `Bill` with more than one `Item` unless I'm mistaken. If you call `Bill.items.count`, it will still return 1, even if you've created 10 `BillItems` referencing the same `Bill` and `Item` (I may be wrong on this but don't think so)